# Reshaping 3D array to 2D

Tags: matlab, reshape

Check out following toy example:

```
m = 3;
n = 3;
Y = rand(m,n,2);
```

for example gives me

> y(:,:,1) =

```
0.8314    0.3993    0.6569
0.8034    0.5269    0.6280
0.0605    0.4168    0.2920
```

y(:,:,2) =

```
0.4317    0.1672    0.1981
0.0155    0.1062    0.4897
0.9841    0.3724    0.3395
```

now when I reshape it using

```
reshape(Y,m*n,2)
```

it disturbs the order and gives me,

> ```
> 0.8314    0.4317
> 0.8034    0.0155
> 0.0605    0.9841
> 0.3993    0.1672
> 0.5269    0.1062
> 0.4168    0.3724
> 0.6569    0.1981
> 0.6280    0.4897
> 0.2920    0.3395
> ```
>
> because here 2nd row should be

```
0.3993    0.1672
```

this can be crosschecked before reshaping by

```
Y(1,1,:)
Y(1,2,:) 
etc.
```

The order changes.

PS : I have huge data to be fed in Neural network and this affects the way my weights are being multiplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) there and then [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), like so -

```
reshape(permute(y,[2,1,3]),[],size(y,3))
```

Sample run -

```
>> y
y(:,:,1) =
       0.8314       0.3993       0.6569
       0.8034       0.5269        0.628
       0.0605       0.4168        0.292
y(:,:,2) =
       0.4317       0.1672       0.1981
       0.0155       0.1062       0.4897
       0.9841       0.3724       0.3395
>> reshape(permute(y,[2,1,3]),[],size(y,3))
ans =
       0.8314       0.4317
       0.3993       0.1672
       0.6569       0.1981
       0.8034       0.0155
       0.5269       0.1062
        0.628       0.4897
       0.0605       0.9841
       0.4168       0.3724
        0.292       0.3395
```

Comment: Thank you.It works.But just reshape should preserve the order. doesn't seem logical ! I will accept the answer

Comment: @Hima If you consider that MATLAB follows col-major indexing, it would make seem a bit more logical. So, the second element is `0.8034` and not `0.3993`. We need `permute` for the same to swap first two dims. That reshape is there finally to give us a 2D version.

Comment: Alright then y(1,2,1) should also give the same but it doesn't.

Comment: @Hima I am lost, `y(1,2,1)` should give same as what?

Comment: @Hima If the proposed solution isn't giving you the desired o/p, consider adding in the same into the question.

Comment: y(1,2,1) before reshaping should be same as second element after reshaping ! No it gives the desired output which is confirmed by my acceptance as answer. Trying to relate elements before and after reshaping.